# How to work with the function that contains this product?

Tags: python, numpy

How to work with this equation :

```
def f(x,y):    
    return ( (7/10)*x**4 - 8*y**2 + 6*y**2 + cos(x*y) - 8*x)


x = np.linspace(-3.1416,3.1416,100) 
y = np.linspace(-3.1416,3.1416,100) 
x,y = np.meshgrid(x,y) 
z = f(x,y) 

TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

The problem is with the cos(x*y)

Comment: What are x and y in the case where this is erroring?

Comment: x = np.linspace(-3.1416,3.1416,100)
y = np.linspace(-3.1416,3.1416,100)

fig = plt.figure()

ejes = Axes3D(fig)  


x,y = np.meshgrid(x,y)


z = f(x,y)

ejes.plot_wireframe(x,y,z)

Comment: just variables. I wanna plot that function f(x,y) at interval given.

Comment: It looks like np.meshgrid is returning an array, I would recommend printing out x and y to see what their value is in this case.

Comment: When I use the function f(x,y) with the cos element it works. I think that the problem is who I call the cos(x*y)

Comment: The function is fine; what you are *passing* to the function is another matter.

Comment: If you just add print(x) and print(y) before your call to f(x, y) I think you will see you're calling the function with arrays which don't cause the basic python arithmetic operations to break but doesn't work with the cos function

Comment: What is `cos`? Is it `math.cos` or `numpy.cos`? Your error would seem to indicate that you are trying to pass a `numpy` array to `math.cos`. Maybe you intended `np.cos(x*y)`?

Comment: @vannserr you should [edit] your question to add more details, such as code that creates a [mre]

Comment: Pranav you're right. Im working with a np.cos, but manipulating this with math.cos. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your x and y that you're passing to your function are likely not ints/floats, which based upon how you're using cos in the function they should be ints/floats. Just check that your x and y are actually what you expect them to be by printing them out. If they do end up being lists just iterate across the lists and call your function for each pair of x and y, or if you are expecting a singular value for x and y then you need to reconsider what you're doing prior to the f(x, y) call. It seems like there's a misunderstanding in what one of the functions you're using prior to your custom function call is actually doing.

Answer (score 4):

You get that error when you pass a numpy array to `math.cos`.

```
>> import math
>> import numpy as np
>> x = np.random.random((3,3))
>> math.cos(x)

TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

But if you use `np.cos`, you get the cosine for each element of `x`.

```
>> np.cos(x)
array([[0.77929073, 0.98196607, 0.99423945],
       [0.99542772, 0.93156929, 0.8161034 ],
       [0.62669568, 0.92407875, 0.76850767]])
```

So don't pass your numpy array to `math.cos`. Pass it to `numpy.cos`.